# STD error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14

I have three class. One is abstract, second is based on the abstract one and its storing pointers in `std::vector` to instances of another.

I want to create `std::shared_ptr` of `ClientRepository` to pass it to the Manager class instance in the future.

There is a template class called "Repository". I want to use it to create a few types of `Repositories`, for example: `CarsRepository`, `ItemsRepository`, etc.

Unfortunately I am getting an error while compiling:

main.cpp:84:139: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 std::shared_ptr, std::vector> > p = std::make_shared;
                                                                                                                                       ^

Repository.hpp

```
#ifndef REPOSITORY_HPP
#define REPOSITORY_HPP

#include <string>

template<typename typeBOOL, typename typeShared_ptr, typename VectorOfSmarPtrs > class Repository
{
    protected:
        VectorOfSmarPtrs nameOfVector;

    public:
        virtual typeBOOL create(const typeShared_ptr&) = 0;
};

#endif
```

ClientRepository.hpp

```
#ifndef CLIENTREPOSITORY_HPP
#define CLIENTREPOSITORY_HPP

#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "Client.hpp"
#include "Repository.hpp"

class ClientRepository : public Repository<bool, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client> > >{
    public:
        bool create(const std::shared_ptr<Client> & newClient) override;
};

#endif
```

ClientRepository.cpp

```
include "ClientRepository.hpp"

bool ClientRepository::create(const std::shared_ptr<Client> & newClient) {
    if(newClient != NULL){
        for(int i = 0; i < this->nameOfVector.size(); i++) {
            if(this->nameOfVector.at(i)->GetPersonalID() == newClient->GetPersonalID()) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        this->nameOfVector.push_back(newClient);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "Client.hpp"
#include "ClientRepository.hpp"
#include "Repository.hpp"

int main(){ 
    ClientRepository x;


    std::shared_ptr<Repository< bool, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> > p = std::make_shared<ClientRepository>;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? What should I change?

Comment: What in the world is a `std::bool`?? `bool` is a keyword :P

Comment: @Rakete Probably adapted from C where the name of the header file `stdbool.h` can be really misleading.

Comment: typeBOOL? Why that?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've changed that. Now its "only" one error.

Comment: @manni66 Its the name of the type. Its easier for me in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss parenthesis:

```
std::shared_ptr<Repository<bool,
                           std::shared_ptr<Client>,
                           std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>>> p
//                                                              ^
    = std::make_shared<ClientRepository>();
//                                      ^^
```

Comment: Now I've got ` error: template argument 1 is invalid
     std::shared_ptr<Repository<bool, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> > p = std::make_shared<ClientRepository>();
                                                                                                                                             ^
`

Comment: Can't you use `auto` ?

Comment: @KKMKK  Count your angle brackets -- '<' versus '>'.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't. It needs to be a `Repository` type.

Comment: After repair the brackets i got another error: `main.cpp:84:124: error: 
conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<Repository<bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client> > > >’ requested
     std::shared_ptr<Repository<bool, std::string, std::shared_ptr<Client>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>>>> p = std::make_shared<ClientRep
                                                                                                                            ^`